# How to load a trained tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am having all kinds of trouble loading a tensorflow model to test on some new data. When I trained the model, I used this:

```
save_model_file = 'my_saved_model'
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(sess, save_model_file)
```

This seems to result in the following files being created:

```
my_saved_model.meta
checkpoint
my_saved_model.index
my_saved_model.data-00000-of-00001
```

I have no idea which of these files I am supposed to pay attention to.

Now the model is trained, and I can't seem to load it or use it without throwing an exception. Here is what I am doing:

```
def neural_net_data_input(data_shape):
    theshape=(None,)+tuple(data_shape)
    return tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=theshape,name='x')

def neural_net_label_input(n_out):
    return tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,n_out),name='one_hot_labels')

def neural_net_keep_prob_input(): 
    return tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name='keep_prob')

def do_generate_network(x):
    #
    # here is where i generate the network layer by layer.
    # this code works fine so i am not showing it here
    #
    pass

#
# Now I want to restore the model
#
tf.reset_default_graph()

input_data_shape=(32,32,1)
final_num_outputs=43

graph1 = tf.Graph()
with graph1.as_default():
    x = neural_net_data_input(input_data_shape)
    one_hot_labels = neural_net_label_input(final_num_outputs)
    keep_prob=neural_net_keep_prob_input()
    logits = do_generate_network(x)
    # Name logits Tensor, so that is can be loaded from disk after training
    logits = tf.identity(logits, name='logits')
    #
    # accuracy: we use this for validation testing
    #
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(one_hot_labels, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name='accuracy')

################################
# Evaluate
################################

new_data=myutils.load_pickle_file(SOME_DATA_FILE_NAME)
new_features=new_data['features']
new_one_hot_labels=new_data['labels']

print('Evaluating on new data...')
with tf.Session(graph=graph1) as sess:
    # Initializing the variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    saver.restore(sess,save_model_file)
    new_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: new_features, one_hot_labels: new_one_hot_labels, keep_prob: 1.})
    print('Testing Accuracy For New Images: {}'.format(new_acc))
```

But when I do this, I get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'save/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'save/Const', does not exist in the graph.
```

So, i tried moving my graph inside the session like this:

```
################################
# Evaluate
################################

print('Evaluating on web data...')
with tf.Session() as sess:

    x = neural_net_data_input(input_data_shape)
    one_hot_labels = neural_net_label_input(final_num_outputs)
    keep_prob=neural_net_keep_prob_input()
    logits = do_generate_network(x)
    # Name logits Tensor, so that is can be loaded from disk after training
    logits = tf.identity(logits, name='logits')
    #
    # accuracy: we use this for validation testing
    #
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(one_hot_labels, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name='accuracy')

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    my_save_dir="/home/carnd/CarND-Traffic-Sign-Classifier-Project"
    load_model_meta_file=os.path.join(my_save_dir,"my_saved_model.meta")
    load_model_path=os.path.join(my_save_dir,"my_saved_model")
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(load_model_meta_file)
    new_saver.restore(sess, load_model_path)

    web_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: web_features, one_hot_labels: web_one_hot_labels, keep_prob: 1.})
    print('Testing Accuracy For Web Images: {}'.format(web_acc))
```

Now it runs without throwing an error, but the accuracy result it prints is 0.02! I am feeding in the very same data that during training I was getting 95% accuracy on. So it appears I am somehow loading my model incorrectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am using tensorflow 1.2 by the way

Answer (score 2):

Steps for loading the trained model:

1. ***Load the graph***:
      You can load the graph using `tf.train.import_meta_graph()`. An example code would be:

   ```
   model_path = "my_saved_model"
   inference_graph = tf.Graph()
   with tf.Session(graph= inference_graph) as sess:
      # Load the graph with the trained states
     loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path+'.meta')
     loader.restore(sess, model_path)
   ```
2. ***Get the tensors:*** Get the tensors need for inference by using `get_tensor_by_name()`. So in your model make sure you name the tensors by name, so that you can call it during inference.

   ```
     #Get the tensors by their variable name 

     _accuracy = inference_graph.get_tensor_by_name('accuracy:0')
     _x  = inference_graph get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
     _y  = inference_graph.get_tensor_by_name('y:0')
   ```
3. ***Test:*** Can do done by using the tensors loaded. `sess.run(_accuracy, feed_dict={_x: ... , _y:...}`